# mensaje <Empty JSON content> soap UI

Tags: java, spring, swagger, soapui

Buenas tengo un objecto que al hacer una consulta a base de datos me devuelve esto : { [] }, pero el soap UI me muestra este mensaje: "Empty JSON content" .

Hay alguna forma que en vez de sacarme este mensaje me saque esto []

Comment: Te refieres a que en lugar de  "Empty JSON content" .muestre "[]" ?

Comment: Si, exactamente eso, estoy usando una clase swagger no sé si puede ser por alguna etiqueta